# Selenium. NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, html, selenium

Всем привет, может кто-то сможет понять в чем проблема данного кода?

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
wd.get('https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/Q14050/entry')
sleep(15)
Molmass = wd.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="sequences"]/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]')
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="decorated-list-item__content">63,616</div>
```

Selector:

```
#sequences > div > div.card__content > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > div.decorated-list-item__content
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="sequences"]/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]
```

Ошибка:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="sequences"]/div/div[2]/section/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=107.0.5304.87)
```

[image: скрин с html]

Comment: а поиск елемента по имени класса не помогает?

Comment: @Dmitry пробовал все варианты поиска, ничего не помогает

Comment: ваша проблема в том, что контент загружается по мере прокрутки страницы, поэтому вы и не можете найти элемент. Вам нужно написать прокрутку вниз, затем выполнить поиск и тогда все найдется.